# Is there any video cutter plugin for cordova phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to know that, is there any video trimming plugin available for phonegap, i have a project from one of my client where i need to capture the video and trim video based on start time & end time.
Say **For Example:** if the video duration is 5 mins then i want to crop it make a new video with start time 0 mins to End time 2 mins, just a normal trimming functionality

Capturing the video in phonegap was pretty easy, but i need a plugin through which i can trim the video. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:
https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor
You can use google to btw :P.

Comment: I have tried this plugin already and was not working initially, but after talking to the suppor team, they fixed the trimming issue. But you can't trim based on start time/End time, they haven't implemented that yet.Thanks a lot, appreciated :)

Comment: Since ffmpeg is taken off from android, this plugin doesn't support trimming in android, only works for iOS.